# Ajax load content in multiple divs with same id/class

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, rss, swiper.js

I'm trying to load a RSS feed into a slider. The slider is in loop mode, so in this mode you will get infinite scrolling and first slides will repeat after last ones. So there are actually 2 slides of my RSS slide.

Now the problem is that the content only loads if there is one div.

My jQuery that loads the rss file:

```
        (function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajaxSetup(
        {
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#rssblok').show();
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#rssblok').show();
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('#rssblok').show();
            }
        });
        var $container = $("#rssblok");
        $container.load("/kantivi/kantivi_rss.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            $container.load('/kantivi/kantivi_rss.php');
        }, 9000);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The kantivi_rss.php file is just an RSS loader and it echo's the content. This all works

Now the part where the feed must be loaded in the slider content looks like this:

```
<?php 
$slider .= '<div id="rssblok">';
                                            $slider .= '<img src="/img/loading.GIF" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />';
                                            $slider .= '</div>';
?>
```

If I put the slider not in a loop, there will be only one

```
<div id="rssblok">
```

and it works great. However in loop mode it will not load the RSS content because there are  2 slides with the `<div id="rssblok">` div in it.

Hopefully the problem is clear, how to fix this?

Comment: ids have to be unique, use a class instead and iterate over the elements of that class

Comment: I had the same idea and tried it with a class.. however it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over all of the containers and apply the load to each one:

```
var $containers = $("#rssblok");
for (var i=0, j=$containers.length; i<j; i++){
    var $container = $($containers[i]);
    $container.load("/kantivi/kantivi_rss.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
        $container.load('/kantivi/kantivi_rss.php');
    }, 9000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I get the idea, however it's still not working. Only in non loop mode.

Comment: You may need a for loop anywhere you are calling $("#rssblock") or $("#loading") if there are multiples of those as well.

If you can create a fiddle that shows the same problem I could create a more specific solution for you.

Comment: Well made a short version of it: http://jsfiddle.net/2PTue/6/
It should post the foo two times, in the two divs.

Comment: It works when you change it to class instead of ID and add a second div with that class: http://jsfiddle.net/2PTue/15/

Comment: Strange enough it does not help for in the slider.. I'll try some other things.

Comment: I did make a better fiddle and your code is working good.. so that is not the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/9VBha/93/
I figured out that the way the content is loaded in the slider (now it's like: 
`$slider .= '<div class="rssblok"></div>'
return $slider`
for every slide. When I echo this div, it will show up but not in my slider. So could the way the div is loaded into the slider could be the problem? Or could the order of the code be an issue?

Comment: I had to manually put the source code for your slider into the fiddle due to cross-domain and permissions issues, but once I did the loop seems to work just fine? Here's the result of my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9VBha/94/

Comment: Yep I know, mine did work fine too, like I said. The only difference between the fiddle and my code is that I place in the div like this:
`<?php $slider .= '<div class="rssblok"></div>' return $slider ?>` So the question is now: could the way the div is loaded into the slider could be the problem? Or could the order of the code be an issue?

Comment: Since PHP is processed server-side, the only problem would be if your code is wrapped in a domReady block or not to ensure that the html is fully loaded before running the JavaScript.